# Create Flutter layout of rows and columns from map

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

How would it be possible to dynamically create rows and columns in flutter using a map element as the schematics?

If I had the following map:

```
   "rows":{
      0:{
        "cols":{
          0:{"text":"ABC"},
          1:{"text":"DEF"},
          2:{"text":"GHI"},
        },
      },
      1:{
        "cols":{
          0:{
            "rows":{
              0:{"text":"JKL"},
              1:{"text":"MNO"}
            },
          },
          1:{"text":"PQR"},
          2:{"text":"STU"},
        },
      },
    },
```

how would I make it into a series of flutter widgets:

```
Row(
  children:[
    Column(children: <Widget>[Text("ABC"),]),
    Column(children: <Widget>[Text("DEF"),]),
    Column(children: <Widget>[Text("GHI"),]),
 ),
Row(
  children:[
    Column(children: 
      Row(children: [
        <Widget>[Text("JKL"),
        <Widget>[Text("MNO"),
      ],
    ),
    Column(children: <Widget>[Text("PQR"),]),
    Column(children: <Widget>[Text("STU"),]),
  ]
)
```

I'd like it so that the number of levels deep is dynamic/nested widgets is *infinite*, that is, it doesn't iterate two levels down and then just stop.

To date, I've tried using for loops inside functions which refer to themselves, but I can't quite get it.

Comment: Is there a reason why they are all objects and no lists where the object has no key?

Comment: Not in relation to this question. If converting elements to lists would assist with the solution, I can retrofit what i need afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a `Map.forEach()` Recursion and validate for `"cols"` and `"rows"`something like this:

```dart
recursiveColsAndRows(Map blob) {
    blob.forEach((key, value) => {
    if(key == "cols") {
      // Do a recursion
      recursiveColsAndRows(value)
    }, 
    if(key == "rows") {
      // Do a recursion
      recursiveColsAndRows(value)
    },
      print(value)
  });
}
```

But with infinite nesting the way you think about, will bring you other big problems very soon, because you cannot display it infinitely without any scrolling features. That means after your third or fourth iteration, you will get an `Overflowed` Error because your Rows fall out of the Screen.

Infinite nesting the way you try to accomplish is not a good approach for displaying different data. Try to create proper widgets which fit your different types of needs.

PS: Are you maybe searching for a [Table feature?](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/explore-table-in-flutter-28726b28b5d6)